# Compare same field with multiple values in MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, select, multiple-columns

can you tell me the best practice to create the following query?

Let's say I have a table with 3 fields`id, owner_id, data`. And I have to do a SELECT query that will return data owned by a lot of people.

I cannot use OR `SELECT data FROM posts WHERE owner_id = x OR owner_id = y` because I can end up with 200 owner ids when I have to do the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT data
FROM   posts
WHERE  owner_id IN (x, y)
GROUP  BY data
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2      // number of owners
```

- [The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

`DISTINCT` keyword is required if `data` is not unique for every `owner_id`.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT owner_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with

```
SELECT data FROM posts WHERE owner_id IN (x,y)
```

The IN statement can be generated from an array :)

Comment: this will return `data` if it is owned by atleast `x` or `y` `owner_id`.